# What is the fastest way to drain all the charges of battery?

Tags: power, batteries, short-circuit, discharge

I need to build battery draining circuit which must finish off battery's charges as fast as possible. I've designed one, but not sure is it optimal one or not? I decided to connect single R to battery as shown in circuit. 
And Since the maximum power which battery can take is

> Pmax=r*(I)^2

and

> R=(V-r*I)/I

, our minimum R must be

> R=(V/(Pmax/r)^0.5)-r

. I thought too much power on battery may cause disaster, output maximum output current must be limited to

> I=(Pmax/r)^0.5

Can this be optimal solution? And I'm not sure if equation for power which battery takes is true or not.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvI6OO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What does the battery supplier state as being the maximum current to take during discharge?

Comment: I don't know. Because my kind of client hasn't determined which kind of battery we will focus on. So I have to make kind of universal equations

Comment: In your question the r represents  the internal resistance, right? Do you think the r is universal for all battery types? If your answer is NO, there can't be a universal super fast drainer. R must be adjusted according to the r and still be limited to peak I limit of the battery.

Comment: Yeah but I just want to check If Equation only is correct or not. I mean can this design is fastest way to discharge it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I mean can this design is fastest way to discharge it?

No, the current taken by the load resistor gets less and less as battery terminal voltage drops. This is because the effective series resistance of the battery increases as it loses charge (generalism alert!).

So, to discharge safely at the maximum rate you need a constant current load similar to this: -

[image]

Vin sets the voltage across Rsense and that determine how much current flows into the BJT collector.

But you need to ensure that you don't go past the point of no-return for the battery or damage may occur. So, use a comparator to switch off the discharge circuit when the battery terminal voltage reaches the lowest point recommended by the manufacturer.

Comment: *"don't go past the point of no-return for the battery or damage may occur"* Here Andy assumes you're using rechargeable batteries which is mentioned nowhere in your question. But Andy's assumption makes sense since discharging non-rechargeable batteries seems like a pointless exercise unless you want to measure their capacity which you do not seem to want.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So I should've been more specific then